# how to get more label with php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to draw multiple series into flotchart.  I'm successfully getting 1 label, but I'm stuck to get more labels with PHP and encode to json.

```
$connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query = "SELECT SC,SR FROM high";
    $result = mysql_query($query);        

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
        $int = $row['SR'];
        $join = intval($int);
        $int2 = $row['SC'];
        $join2 = intval($int2);
        $dataset1[] = array($join2,$join);
    }

    $final = json_encode($dataset1);
echo $final;
```

**RESULT**

```
[[1,3],[2,20],[3,30],[4,10],[5,4],[6,40],[7,67],[8,100],[9,5],[10,11]]
```

**Parse JSON to Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    dataType:'json',  /*to avoid calling JSON.parse(data) in your callback function*/
    url: 'chart-data.php',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);//as mentioned in comments
        //1.either call plot again 
        /*calling plot as seen in your code - start*/

        var d1 = data;/* JSON.parse(data) */
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), 
            [{
                label: "SCR",
                data: d1,
            },
            /*{
                label: "SCR",
                data: d1,
                },*/
            ],
```

FOKUS ON **{label: "SCR",data: d1,},**

Question: How to parse JSON data to JS like :

```
[ { label: "Foo", data: [ [10, 1], [17, -14], [30, 5] ] },
  { label: "Bar", data: [ [11, 13], [19, 11], [30, -7] ] }
]
```

I'm just trying to use array:

```
$s= array('label'=> "aaaa",
    'data'=> $final);
print_r($s);
```

and get result

```
Array ( [label] => aaaa [data] => [[1,3],[2,20],[3,30],[4,10],[5,4],[6,40],[7,67],[8,100],[9,5],[10,11]] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your array before encode it in PHP like this:

```
$dataset = array("label" => "FOO/BAR", "data" => array(/* Your `data` array */));
```

And also append all your `label/data` values to `dataset` variable and finally encode and echo it

Comment: can "label" and "data" didn't have string character ? **""**

Comment: string character = " "

Comment: these keys (of array) can include all kind of variable, what you mean? I didn't understand...

Comment: when i try your suggestion, this result is {"label":"foo","data":
how remove string char " " between label and data ? just only  {label:"foo",data: arraydata}

Comment: Non!!! when you want to create an array your array indexes must be number or string (associative array). and if it is possible, I don't know how